# Facebook error 200 (Permission error) when posting a comment

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Sometimes when I want to post a comment to a post through the graph API, Facebook gives me this error:

```
Caught exception: (#200) Permissions error
```

Does anyone know why I get that error?
It's only sometimes I get it.

I've checked the access token and that is fine without any problems.

Looking forward to hear from some Facebook experts :-)

Comment: what permissions are you using, and are you trying with an admin account of the app?

Comment: I've these permissions: public_profile, email, publish_actions, user_groups

I'm trying to post a comment in a update the user have made.
The weird thing is, that it's working 8/10 times on different posts, so it's quite hard to figured out where the error is

Comment: publish_actions and user_groups have to be approved by facebook, else they only work for app admins. are you sure you are trying with an app admin only?

Comment: Yes. All users are app admins, so that shouldn't be the problem